# Delete Row from Table with a Composite Key

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running MySQL Server 5.6 on Windows Server 2008 R2.  I have the following InnoDB table with a composite primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE `myschema`.`mytable` (
    `id_1` TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `id_2` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL
     PRIMARY KEY (`id_1`, `id_2`));
```

I am trying to write a SQL statement that will delete a row in this table.  I have tried to execute the following statements in MySQL Workbench:

```
DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE `id_1`=12 AND `id_2`=238;
DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE `id_1`='12' AND `id_2`='238';
DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE ((`id_1`=12) AND (`id_2`=238));
DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE ((`id_1`=CAST(12 AS UNSIGNED)) AND (`id_2`=CAST(238 AS UNSIGNED)));
DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE ((`id_1`=CAST('12' AS UNSIGNED)) AND (`id_2`=CAST('238' AS UNSIGNED)));
DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE ((`id_1`='12') AND (`id_2`='238'));

DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE (`id_1`, `id_2`) IN (12, 238);
DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE (`id_1`, `id_2`) IN (CAST(12 AS UNSIGNED), CAST(238 AS UNSIGNED));
DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE (`id_1`, `id_2`) IN (CAST('12' AS UNSIGNED), CAST('238' AS UNSIGNED));
DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE (`id_1`, `id_2`) IN ('12', '238');
```

and in every case, I get the following error:

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ' AND '
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE:**

The problem was caused by a defective BEFORE DELETE trigger that I didn't realize was on the table.  All the DELETE FROM statements worked fine after I removed the trigger.  This was very frustrating as the error message gave no indication that the problem was occurring in a trigger. Thanks to everyone for their inputs!

Comment: In a WHERE you are comparing a number with a string.

Comment: Try adding quotes in your CAST('12' AS UNSIGNED)

Comment: Not in the first query he isn't.

Comment: @Mihai Thanks for your comment...I just tried your suggestion and I get the same error...I've added it to the list of things tried.

Comment: @HydroPowerDeveloper for both sides?

Comment: @Mihai Yes, for both sides...BTW: The corresponding SELECT statement works just fine...this is really strange! =)

Comment: Isolate the statement,remove one by one.

Comment: The first query in your set should execute successfully.  Since there is no logical reason for this, look for silly ones.  Start by adding a space after the equal signs.

Comment: @Mihai I'm not sure I understand your suggestion...isn't that what I've been doing?

Comment: @Dan_Bracuk I agree, there is no logical reason for this.  I've added spaces as you suggested, but I still get the same error...the funny thing is that for all the WHERE statements that I've tried the corresponding SELECT statements work just fine.  I'm wondering if this is a MySQL Workbench problem.

Comment: Oh boy...I feel stupid...the problem was caused by a BEFORE DELETE trigger that I didn't know was on the table...once I removed the trigger the DELETE FROM statement worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure it is a problem with your parenthesis.  Let me know if this works

```
DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE `id_1`=12 AND `id_2`=238;
```

or potentially MySQL is complaining about using integers (which it shouldn't be)

```
DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE `id_1`='12' AND `id_2`='238';
```

Comment: @Sam_Sullivan Thanks for your comment...unfortunately I get the same error...I'll add that syntax to my list of things tried.

Comment: @HydroPowerDeveloper have you tried doing the same query with a `SELECT * FROM` syntax instead of `DELETE FROM`?  Also, see if you can solve this by disabling InnoDB strict mode (this wouldn't necessarily be the best fix): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/innodb-other-changes-strict-mode.html

Comment: @Sam_Sullivan I just tried a SELECT using the same WHERE statement and it returns the row that I want to delete...I'll try to disable the InnoDB strict mode...I'll let you know in a minute.

Comment: @Sam_Sullivan Humm...this is really strange...I just checked my server configuration and I have innodb_strict_mode = OFF.

Comment: @Sam_Sullivan I also get the same error when I write the statement "SET SESSION innodb_strict_mode=OFF;" just before the DELETE statement.

Comment: @HydroPowerDeveloper what error do you receive on this query ```DELETE FROM `mytable` WHERE (`id_1`, `id_2`) IN (12, 238);```?

Comment: @Sam_Sullivan I get the following error "Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 2 column(s)"

Comment: @Sam_Sullivan It seems to want parenthesis around "(2, 238)" as in 
"((2, 238))"...in which case I get the original error message.

Comment: Honestly I am lost.  Try it without the ticks (\`)?  Try DELETEing a row by just one of your two primary keys (`WHERE id_1=12`)?

Comment: @Sam_Sullivan The problem was caused by a "defective" BEFORE DELETE trigger that I didn't know was on the table.  All the DELETE FROM statements worked perfectly after the trigger was removed.  This was a very frustrating error as the message gave no indication that it was happening in the trigger.  Thanks again for all your help...it is appreciated! :)